# ng-view isn't being populated with the template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, url-routing, ng-view

Consider [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xRO5BnTYAbNkH8DTmHSg). I think I've set up everything correctly, but my templates aren't getting loaded into the div with the `ng-view` directive.

My routes are configured:

```
routes.forEach(function (r) {
    $routeProvider.when(r.url, r.templateUrl);
});
$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
```

And my routes are:

```
return [
    {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'main.html'
    }, {
        url: '/games',
        templateUrl: 'games.html'
    }
];
```

First of all, my navigation doesn't seem to work, but also, even when I'm in the root (when the path is `/`), my main.html template isn't loaded into the ng-view. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The function definition is:

   ```
   when(path, route);
   ```

   Where `route` is an `object`:

   ```
   routes.forEach(function (r) {
       $routeProvider.when(r.url, { templateUrl: r.templateUrl });
   });
   ```
2. Change `href` to:

   ```
   <li><a href="#/">Main</a></li>
   <li><a href="#/games">Games</a></li>
   ```